# Put margins on a paragraph inside a button

Tags: html, css

There is a button with the paragraph "Restaurants" in it. When I try to create a margin for it, it doesn't do anything. How do you properly use margins for the button?

#### CSS

```css
.buttonp{
    margin-right: 300px;
 }
```

#### HTML

```html
<button class="buttons" 
        inline="true"
        style="margin-left: 150px;margin-right: 20px;">
    <p id="6" class="buttonp">
        Restaurants
    </p>
                
</button>
```

Comment: @MisterJojo I strongly agree 

Comment: Use a space in your class declaration .button p

Answer (score 0):

I cheek your code you use several time css inside style and style sheet CSS I suggested you use CSS in one side.. if you have specific class then use this class and CSS specific class... here my code

```
.buttonp{
    margin-right: 300px;
     display : block;
 }
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.buttons{
    padding: 300px;
}
```

### Padding vs Margin

For example, if you have a element, then put margin in it, you make space and push away other elements within 300px, but the element stays the same size.

If padding, it is the opposite. The element will change size and increase 300px size.